# Call Delphi's class from java

Tags: java, java-native-interface

The question is whether can I create an instance of class (which is situated in .dll and has written in Delphi) and call method from it using Java.

I have found a lot of solutions about how to call native routines or methods in Java. What about classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest is using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) project. You'd have to create a set of functions in your DLL which could be called. Alternatively you can create a wrapper DLL if original cannot be changed

Comment: Can I use strong-typed calling from Java without any wrapping dll?

Comment: Only with simple types and if the function is exported in your dll